# Said al hamichya instead of birkas hamazon. What do I do?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, bentching, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

If one had 'pas habah bekisnin' thinking that he needs to make a mezonos followed by al hamichya, and after doing so discovers that he should have washed, said hamotzi and then birkas hamazon, what should be done now after he has said al hamichya?

Comment: Easiest solution - wash and eat another piece.

Comment: @DanF I think I recall reading that in SA.

Comment: @Ploni This wasn't anything I recall from SA. It's the most logical "general" halachic doubtful food-related answer that I've seen. It's almost on par with the common answer I get when I ask a rav, "What's the bracha for sushi?" (different answers from different people, on this.) Rabbis are sometimes embarrassed to just say, "I don't know" (BAD quality, IMO), so they answer, "Why don't you just wash and eat a piece of bread, then it's part of your meal?" I answer "because bread ruins my appetite for the sushi - that's why I don't do it."

Comment: IIRC, there's a story in Talmud in which one Rav made a declaration that "covered" all the points of Birkat HaMazon, preventing the others present from having a Zimun. In a related manner, some are careful not to pronounce Shem Hashem in Tzur MiShelo due to exactly this concern. Bracha Me'ayn Shalosh is intentionally constructed to mirror normal bentsching, so if the former cases are a concern, then the latter would certainly seem to fulfill your obligation to bentsch.

Comment: A quick Web search found me http://www.revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/msh210/1904 and http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=847 , which have some citations.

Answer (score 2):

There is much discussion about this topic by many Acharonim. Rabbi Braun discusses it [here](https://www.halacha2go.com/php/h2go/home2.php?number=438) and more in detail in the Hebrew mareh mekomos on that halacha. The consensus is that one is not Yotzei and needs to bentch again as discussed in that source at length with many sources.

There is more debate about whether the obligation to repeat bentching remains Medooraisa or becomes Medarabun (meaning that one doesn't even fufill his Torah obligation with al hamichya. See there for sources.)*

The Rebbe in a [letter](https://www.igrot.com/answer/4/24) to an individual who asked the same question states that the reason for the need to repeat bentching is because the 'ברכה מעין ג does not include ברית  ותורה. (See Rabbi Braun's discussion on this and his other reason he brings down.)
[image]

*See for example [Sharei Tzion to the Mishnah Berurah Siman 168](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60387&st=&pgnum=142) note 71.